# Recording data into text file in external storage continuously

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am writing a program that determine the sun position and then track it. I need to record the variables that affect the results and the final results into a text file in external storage. I know that we can use the `OutputStream` and `OutputStreamWriter` to do it.

But I am having one problem in that my data is recording in every few seconds. Is there anyway I can record my data into the same file but next line? It means that if I am having 100k of data, my text file will have 100k lines of recorded data. Is that possible to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file in append mode and simply append the new lines to it.